# grouping categories for weight restriction in woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to group together multiple categories in a weight restriction for the woocommerce cart. Right now its set to individual arrays per category and just not sure how to modify the total weight for multiple categories to restrict.

I'm using [Restrict cart weight per individual product category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72812167/11987538) answer code for one category at a time with weight per category.

I'm thinking Id have to group the categories by slug in the first section and then also allow them to total up at the bottom in the settings section and the error function.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a multi part update to allow for the weight restrictions to check for if there is a group of categories (array) and if so combine weights for total limit in addition to the separate weights per category.

Part 1
inside your category array replace the 'category-1' with

```
array('category-1a','category-1b','category-2d')
```

Then when you loop through settings array check if the category is an array and then loop for weight total across all categories before moving on to the single category weights.

```
if (is_array($setting['category'])) {
foreach ($setting['category'] as $cat) {
if (has_term ($cat, 'product_cat', $product_id) ) {
$settings[$key]['total'] += $product_quantity * $product_weight;
continue;
```

Then continue on with the weight check as normal ensuring you use else if to kick it off.

```
else if ( has_term( $setting['category'], 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
```